# How to make special French keyboard characters work in MS RDC?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, remote-desktop

I'm on a Macbook Pro with a French Keyboard. Keyboard layout works fine when connecting to Windows XP Professional but I cannot get certain keys to work:

For example **$**, **&**, **é**, **§** and **@** etc. work fine.

- Forward slash `/` using <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> works.
- Backslash `\` using <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> does not work.
- Pipe `|` using <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> does not work.

Is there any configuration that I can do to make my keyboard work?

I've had this issue on my Windows VM in Virtual Box but fixed it with a custom keyboard layout. However when connecting to servers and workstations over the network this is not a solution since I can not configure each machine I need to connect to.

Under preferences, if I disable the Alt key it still does not work and on-top of that working without an Alt Key in Windows is no fun.

Comment: Is the Windows system you're connecting to set to use a French keyboard?

Comment: Yes, windows places it to (FR) on login

Comment: If I switch to EN I have to press shift-dollar to get a backslash. Would prefer a French layout :)

Comment: Another test I tried that does also not work: Connecting from my XP VM via Remote Desktop. Strange that it does not work since in the VM my keys are mapped to work.

Comment: I could get a backslash using Ctrl+Alt+8... The Windows on-screen keyboard is helpful for figuring out what's going on

Comment: I'm interested in making the mac combo Alt-Shift-/ (for backslash) work via RDC. Thanks to Joel I'm close by pressing Crtl-Alt-8 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of backslash <kbd>\</kbd>, the problem is a difference between where Macintosh French keyboards put the backslash (which is <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>), and where Windows French keyboards put the backslash (which is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>).

Since the way Remote Desktop works is that scancodes, not characters, are sent to the remote system, you have to honor the Windows keyboard and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to get a backslash.

Pipe <kbd>|</kbd> is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>

I was able to debug this using the on-screen keyboards, which both Macintosh and Windows support.

Comment: Still does not work for me. Seems the right-alt scancode is ignored when sent from my Mac. The only way I could get it to work is to use the kebyboard layout editor to map pipe to Ctrl+Alt+Shift+L. It seems Mac Alt is always translated as plain Alt and Alt Gr is gone.

Comment: I've reset my keyboard layout and it works now as the you suggested. But that's the "traditional" french layout.

Answer (score 2):

I press left <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + right <kbd>⌘</kbd> + right <kbd>⌥</kbd> key on my mac to imitate <kbd>AltGr</kbd> when using remote desktop to a windows computer

I can type special characters and shortcuts that need the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key on the remote PC.

Comment: Thanks ! this works fine on my macbook M2

Answer (score 2):

In windows symbols can be inserted by pressing Shift + relevant number key to insert symbol.

When using a macbook on Microsoft Remote Desktop connection, you are required to Hold down Cmd + Shift + Number Key.

This is the hidden option for inserting symbols into Windows machines over Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection.